# EF Core dynamic filter on boolean column

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to apply a filter on boolean column which I will get it from the frontend as a parameter. It may be true, false or both. I can use the if statement to run the query but I need to add other methods like Take, Skip, OrderBy etc., which I have removed it for brevity. Is there any way to build the dynamic expression for below condition

```
if(parameter == "true")
_db.Employees.Where(e => e.Status = true)
else if (parameter == "false")
_db.Employees.Where(e => e.Status = false)
else
_db.Employees.ToList() //Return both true and false
```

Comment: A boolean can't be "both". In SQL it can be true, false or NULL, meaning "has no value". The first two options check for true or false but exclude NULLs.

Comment: You're already creating the query dynamically. Every LINQ call returns a new IQueryable instance. You can use `if (x){ query=query.Where(...);}` to add different conditions.

Comment: I will get the string parameter which will be "true", "false", "both" or empty

Answer (score 1):

LINQ queries are *already* dynamic. Every LINQ operator returns a new IQueryable<> query. You can construct a query bit by bit based on various conditions this way, eg :

```
var query=db.Employees.AsQueryable();
if(status=="Active")
{
    query=query.Where(e=>e.Active);
}
if(dateAscending)
{
    query=query.OrderBy(e=>e.Date);
}

if(page==1)
{
    query=query.Take(pageSize);
}
else
{
    query=query.Skip(page*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}

...
var employees=await query.ToListAsync();
```

The tricky part is handling NULLs. In SQL, NULL means there's no value and any comparison with NULL returns NULL itself, which is translated as false. If `Status` or `Active` are nullable, you can't return any rows with NULLs by comparing with false. You'll have to compare with `null` explicitly. EF Core translates that to `IS NULL`.

Using a switch expression you can combine the various Status checks with this:

```
query = (status) switch 
        {
            "true"  => query.Where(e=>e.Status),
            "false" => query.Where(e=>!e.Status),
            "both"  => query.Where(e=> e.Status !=null)
            _       => query.Where(e=>e.Status == null)
        };
```

This expression assumes that an empty string is meant to match NULLs. `both` means retrieving TRUE and FALSE but not NULL.

If don't care about NULLs, this can be simplified to :

```
query = (status) switch 
        {
            "true"  => query.Where(e=>e.Status),
            "false" => query.Where(e=>!e.Status),
            _       => query
        };
```

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos. Let me try to test it.